# Winning criterion: shortest compressed source code

Tags: discussion

codegolf.stackexchange.com, I saw [this](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/play.php) and thought of you...

> We start with the source-code markup you can see, remove comments, remove duplicate whitespace characters, and then apply minimum GZip compression. The Code-used measurement is the size in bytes of that GZip compressed source-code file.
>
> Thanks to Brian Hurt for the idea of using size of compressed source code instead of lines of code.

Is there any reason that this wouldn't be considered sufficiently objective to be used in a winning criterion for golf-style questions?

What details would need to be specified to make it objective? Version, settings?

I had a brief glance at the existing tags, but please let me know if a relevant tag already exists or if there are already questions using this criterion which I have failed to find.

Comment: Why? What's the point of this, and what value would it add to the site?

Comment: @Doorknob That's why I'd like to see discussion. Does anyone have reason to think it would change the balance between different programming languages? Would anyone be interested in such questions? Would it create interest or annoyance? Would the extra work be worthwhile? My main question is simply "is this objective", but I'm interested in general discussion and opinions and potential pitfalls too.

Comment: 1) Yes, it's objective. 2) IMO it would be annoying. For golf I can tell in an instant whether a modification will save characters. Zip is not like that. For even the most minor changes, I'd have to edit/zip/check. I imagine that would make iteratively golfing down a solution a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following up on Geobits' comment, it *is* a objective criterion, but I would be unlikely to play because who wants to bother.

Not that I have had much time for any games recently.

Besides, it presumably incentives repetitive code, and where's the fun in that?